# Replacing $x,y$ in $f(x,y,z)$ with values from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this using map or apply, but its not occurring to me.

Suppose I have a function $f(x,y,z)= x+y+z)$

And I want to evaluate $f(x,y,1)$ for $\{x,y\} ∈ \{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$

What is the best way to do this?

---

Examples:

If I use
`f[x_,y_,z_]:= x+y+z; f[#1,#2,1]&/@ {{1,2},{3,4}}`

this will give me things like `{{2+#2,3+#2}}.`

On the other hand, `Apply` works on a single element
`f[#1,#2,1]& @@ {1,2}`
but not on a list such as `{{1,2},{3,4}}`. On the list it gives me `{f[1,3,1],f[2,4,1]`

I am not sure how to go from the case of a single pair to a list of pairs

Comment: Tp apply to all cross pairs: `Outer[f[#1, #2, 1] &, xList, yList]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
```

Try `@@@` ([`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) at `Level` 1):

```
f[#,#2, 1] & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> ```
> {4, 8}
> ```

Comment: Ahhh, I think I see now. When I use `@@`, (which I think applies at level 0), uses `List[1,2]` for the first argument, and `List[3,4]` for the second. Whereas apply at level 1 applies the function to each part on level 1 of the expression. Thank you very much! I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, quick follow-up question: Why use SlotSequence `##` instead of `f[#1,#2,1]`?  Both work for me in the simply example. Is it just for generality?

Comment: @user106860, I changed it to `#, #2`. The two ways give different results when fed a  list like `{{1},{1,2,3}`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

We can set `1` as [Optional](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) default value of `z`

```
f[x_, y_, z_ : 1] := x + y + z
```

Now we can do

```
f @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

{4, 8}

```
f @@@ {{1, 2, 2}, {3, 4, 2}}
```

{5, 9}

```
f[##, 2] & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

{5, 9}

Since V 13.1 we can replace `@@@` with `MapApply` (which is often
useful regarding operator precedence)

```
MapApply[f] @ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

{4, 8}

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z
```

---

Using `Map` at level `2`:

```
m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

Map[f[Sequence @@ ##, 1] &, {m}, {2}][[1]]

(*{4, 8}*)
```

Or using `Outer`:

```
Diagonal@Outer[f[##, 1] &, Sequence @@ Thread@m]

(*{4, 8}*)
```